# How a wedge is two inclined planes?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, geometry

All sources say a wedge is simply two inclined planes. I see how this is true geometrically, but I don't get how this is true functionally.

In an inclined plane, the amount of force required to be applied is reduced but the ***distance over which it is applied is increased***.

If I understand correctly a wedge multiplies the applied vertical force shown below and routes it sideways. ***What are we trading here to get this force multiplication?***

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as you said, they are trading displacement.

The work you are doing by applying the force vertically is equal to the magnitude of that force by the displacement along which you apply the force. This work is mainly put into the permanent tearing of the wood in two pieces (and friction).

This tearing is in fact achieved by the lateral forces, which are rather big. They can become big because of the small slope of the wedge, which translates your bigger vertical movement into a smaller lateral movement. This is the same principle behind a screw-driven press.

In the end, the work done by those large forces applied along a small displacement is roughly the same made by your vertical force along a longer movement.

Perhaps a different perspective can help: You could say that the forces applied by the wood on the wedge, trying to stop it advancing are not very effective, since they are mainly squishing the wedge. So yes, they are very large forces, but they are directed in an ineffective direction. That is why their total work in the end is the same as your optimally directed, although weaker force.

Answer (score 2):

Quite simply, say your wedge is 6 inches long, and tapers up to to 1 inch thick at the wide end. If you put the edge in a crack and push it in 6 inches it will open the crack to 1 inch, a mechanical advantage.

Answer (score 1):

$$\text{Imagine a slope with angle }\alpha$$

[image]

The work required to simply lift an object of mass *m* at height H is given by:
$$W_1=-mgH$$
if we instead use the inclined plane and slide it the force will be smaller, but the path will be longer.
$$W_2=-mg\sin(\alpha)L$$
Note however, that:
$$L\sin(\alpha)=H\implies W_1=W_2 $$
Thus we see that amount of work is the same in both cases (as it should be by conservation of energy).
However in one scenario, we applied stronger force over a shorter distance.

This should give you an answer what we are trading here.

As for an axe, the efficiency mainly comes from the fact, that most of it's the energy is spent on splitting the material, not on compressing it, crushing it or giving it kinetic energy. The edge of an axe is sharp, thus it produces a large pressure on the object easily cutting it (idealized case).

Note that in order to cut a material, we must displace it. As in case of an incline, we see that if an object is moving on incline (which is equivalent as if the object is stationary and incline is moving, like in axe scenario), we can 'lift' it with smaller force.